# XSLT + Parsing Strings with multiple criterias

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to parse the following message string:

```
"Row 1> testdata1 |Row 5> testdata2 |Row 7> testdata3"
```

into a HTML table format:

```
<tr>
  <td>Row 1</td><td>testdata1</td>
  <td>Row 5</td><td>testdata2</td>
  <td>Row 7</td><td>testdata3</td>
</td>
```

Here is my current attempt:

```
<xsl:template match="Row">
  <tbody><xsl:apply-templates/></tbody>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="col1" >
  <xsl:call-template name="parseStr" >
    <xsl:with-param name="txt" select="text()" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="parseStr">
  <xsl:param name="txt" select="''" />
    <tr><xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($txt, '>')" >
        <td><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($txt, '>')" /></td><td><xsl:value-of select="substring-after($txt, '>')" /></td>
      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:otherwise>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="$txt" /></td>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose></tr>

    <xsl:variable name="leftStr" select="substring-after($txt, '|')" />
    <xsl:if test="string-length($leftStr)>1" >
      <xsl:call-template name="parseStr" >
        <xsl:with-param name="txt" select="$leftStr" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>
```

This XSLT provides the correct table structure. I am having difficulties separating the testdata strings after the initial > break.

Output:

```
<tr>
  <td>Row 1</td><td>testdata1 |Row 5> testdata2 |Row 7> testdata3</td>
  <td>Row 5</td><td>testdata2 |Row 7> testdata3</td>
  <td>Row 7</td><td>testdata 3</td>
</tr>
```

**UPDATE**
I've figured out how to grab the text inbetween the strings. I added the following:

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($txt, '>')" /></td><td><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before($txt, '|'), '>')" /></td>
```

However, I am missing the last parsed message "testdata3".

Additionally, here is the original XML:

```
<Rowsets>
  <Rowset>
    <Row>
      <col1>Row 1> testdata1 |Row 5> testdata2 |Row 7> testdata3</col1>
    </Row>
  </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

success! I figured out the solution to this; however, there may be an easier/cleaner way... here is my solution if you're interested :-)

```
 <xsl:template name="parseStr">
   <xsl:param name="txt" select="''" />
     <tr><xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="contains($txt, '|')" >
         <td><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($txt, '>')" /></td><td><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before($txt, '|'), '>')"/></td>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($txt, '>')" /></td><td><xsl:value-of select="substring-after($txt, '>')" /></td>
       </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose></tr>

   <xsl:variable name="leftStr" select="substring-after($txt, '|')" />
   <xsl:if test="string-length($leftStr)>1" >
     <xsl:call-template name="parseStr" >
       <xsl:with-param name="txt" select="$leftStr" />
     </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The "message string" is not XML. Is it part of some XML structure that you are not showing?

Comment: I've updated my post with the XML

Comment: Unfortunately, as you have realised, XSLT is not the best tool for parsing non-XML data such as yours. Your choice of recursive templates is the neatest way to complete this task.

Comment: @Nat: Your absolute statement about XSLT is wrong, as can be seen from my answer: in XSLT 2.0 and later text-processing is easy and natural.

Comment: Good point. Am stuck in Microsoft land, where XSLT 2.0 has not been implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I. This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <tr>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </tr>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()" name="makeTDs">
  <xsl:param name="pStr" select="."/>

  <xsl:if test="string($pStr)">
   <xsl:variable name="vText" select="concat($pStr, ' |')"/>
   <xsl:variable name="vPair" select=
    "substring-before($vText, ' |')"/>
   <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($vPair, '> ')"/>
   </td>
   <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($vPair, '> ')"/>
   </td>

   <xsl:call-template name="makeTDs">
     <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select=
      "substring-after($pStr, ' |')"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the this XML document**:

```
<t>Row 1> testdata1 |Row 5> testdata2 |Row 7> testdata3</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<tr>
   <td>Row 1</td>
   <td>testdata1</td>
   <td>Row 5</td>
   <td>testdata2</td>
   <td>Row 7</td>
   <td>testdata3</td>
</tr>
```

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., ' \|')">
     <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '> ')">
       <td><xsl:sequence select="."/></td>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </tr>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**this transformation, when applied on the same XML document (above) produces the same correct result:**

```
<tr>
   <td>Row 1</td>
   <td>testdata1</td>
   <td>Row 5</td>
   <td>testdata2</td>
   <td>Row 7</td>
   <td>testdata3</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling a little to understand your input XML - did it get messed up by the editor. It certainly doesn't appear to to be well formed XML and I don't see any `<Row>` or `<Col>` elements.

However, this line looks wrong:

```
<xsl:param name="txt" select="''" />
```

I think that it should just read

```
<xsl:param name="txt">
```